# Update label text from annotation title

Tags: ios, segue, mkannotation, uistoryboardsegue

Im trying to update a label in the next view with an annotations title on segue, Im not sure how to do this, but working on the lines of this. Any suggestion or does this need to be done where the annotation is created?

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"pushShare"])
    {
        ShareViewController *vc = (ShareViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        [vc fromLabel.text = StartAnnotation.title];
    }
}
```

**Update**
The annotation is created when a button is clicked, a pin is dropped on the user location and the annotation title displays the address, Iv tried updating a label in the same view with the title but having trouble with that aswell.

code for creating the annotation

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D theCoordinate = {_map.userLocation.location.coordinate.latitude,_map.userLocation.location.coordinate.longitude};
CLLocation *currentLocation = [[CLLocation alloc]
                               initWithLatitude:_map.userLocation.location.coordinate.latitude
                               longitude:_map.userLocation.location.coordinate.longitude];

NSLog(@"self.geocoder=%@", self.geocoder);
[self.geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:currentLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemark, NSError *error) {

    NSString *address = @"Address unknown";
    NSLog(@"geocoder error=%@", error);

    if (placemark.count > 0)
    {
        CLPlacemark *topResult = [placemark objectAtIndex:0];
        address = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@ %@", topResult.subThoroughfare, topResult.thoroughfare, topResult.subLocality, topResult.locality];
    }
StartAnnotation *startPoint = [[StartAnnotation alloc]init];
startPoint.coordinate = theCoordinate;
startPoint.title = address;
startPoint.subtitle = @"Start Point";

[self.map addAnnotation:startPoint];
[self.map selectAnnotation:startPoint animated:YES];
}];
//e.g. fromLabel.text = StartAnnotation.title;
```

Comment: What you're doing looks pretty good. But (1) it is probably not a good idea to attempt to configure a label belonging to a "foreign" view controller directly (at this time, that label probably won't even exist); call a method of that view controller and let _it_ configure its own interface as appropriate. (2) The big problem here is clearly learning the `title` you are after. You just have to plan ahead. How you will do this depends on all sorts of stuff that we can't see, e.g. how did this `title` get derived in the first place?

Comment: updated regarding 1 and 2

Answer (score 0):

You can handle **`didSelectAnnotationView`** to detect when a user tapped on your **`MKAnnotationView`**, like in this example:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{
    [mapView deselectAnnotation:view.annotation animated:YES];

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:YOUR_SEGUE_ID
                              sender:view];
}
```

Then in **`prepareForSegue`** extract the title of the annotation and use it:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:YOUR_SEGUE_ID])
    {
        UIView *annotationView = (UIView *)sender;

        ShareViewController *vc = (ShareViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        vc.textToSetOnTheLabel = annotationView.annotation.title;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have more than one annotation, not sure if this will help, e.g. if I select a different annotation will the title be used from it.